# Registration Check not working with PDO connection

Tags: php, pdo

Hello I am trying to modify a simple registration form check. If a username is occupied than show error, in my case I am trying to add one more field from the database so I will have in this case 2 checks, one of username and one with passport number, obviously the code which I did so far is not working very correct, if there is somebody that can help, I will be very thankful.

```
$username = ( $_POST['username']);
$cedula = ( $_POST['passport']);
$con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
$sthandler = $con->prepare("SELECT username,passport FROM users WHERE username = :username, passport = :passport");
$sthandler->execute(array(':username'=>$username));
$sthandler->execute(array(':passport'=>$passport));
if ( $sthandler->rowCount() > 0 ) { echo ('Sorry this user name is occupied '.$_POST['username'].' try another.'); }
if ( $sthandler->rowCount() > 0 ) { echo ('Sorry this passport Number is occupied N: '.$_POST['cedula'].' try another.');}

else{ HERE GOES THE CODE IF EVERYTHING IS OKAY TO GO AND REGISTER.
```

Comment: Where did `$passport` come from?

Comment: Why don't you just make 2 select queries on the passport number and username then if that doesn't give any rows add an insert query...

Comment: this question appears to be offtopic because it's on a silliest typo. Nobody cares though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $username = ( $_POST['username']);
    $passport = ( $_POST['passport']);
    $con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
    $stm = $con->prepare("SELECT username,cedula FROM users WHERE username = :username or passport = :passport");
    $stm->bindParam(":username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stm->bindParam(":passport", $passport, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stm->execute();
    $result = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if ( count($result)>1 || $result[0]['username'] == $username ) { echo ('Sorry this user name is occupied '.$_POST['username'].' try another.'); }
    if ( count($result)>1 || $result[0]['passport'] == $passport ) { echo ('Sorry this passport Number is occupied N: '.$_POST['passport'].' try another.');}
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /register.php on line 321

Comment: You've got more typos in there than the OP originally had.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object in register.php on line 323